# How to format datetime output in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Have a program to get a date count down. I don't want to print the milliseconds, please help here is my program in python:

```
import time
import datetime
while (datetime.datetime.now() != datetime.datetime (2018,5,5,19,30)):
    print (datetime.datetime (2018,5,5,19,30) - datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

This is my current output: `54 days, 3:54:53.603289`

Would like: `54 days, 3:54:53`, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`datetime.replace(microsecond=0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace), which will:

> Return a datetime with the same attributes, except for those
>   attributes given new values by whichever keyword arguments are
>   specified.

```
import time
import datetime
while (datetime.datetime.now() != datetime.datetime (2018,5,5,19,30)):
    print (datetime.datetime (2018,5,5,19,30) - datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Output:

```
54 days, 3:49:31
54 days, 3:49:30
54 days, 3:49:29
54 days, 3:49:28
54 days, 3:49:27
54 days, 3:49:26
54 days, 3:49:25
54 days, 3:49:24
54 days, 3:49:23
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, there are no good formatting options for a `timedelta` object. I would recommend you pre-calculate an `end_time` and also use `<` rather than waiting for the times to match. In the event your PC is busy at the exact second, your loop might miss the match. By using `<` it will also catch it:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

end_time = datetime(2018, 5, 5, 19, 30)

while datetime.now() < end_time:
    print(end_time - datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
    time.sleep(1.0)
```